# Response status 200 but no JSON

Tags: php, json, api, rest, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send mails but its from my localhost in xampp. When I test my API in Postman, it takes too long to process the request but renders response status 200 but no JSON response returned. Below are my codes.

```
    public function actionSendMail() {
    //Getting request from frontend
    $request = file_get_contents('php://input');

    //Decoding input into an array
    $input = json_decode($request, true);

    //Validating request
    if (is_null($input)) {
        $response = json_encode(['error' => 'Bad Input']);
        die($response);

    } else {
        //mail parameters
        $to      = $input['to'];
        $subject = $input['subject'];
        $body    = $input['body'];
        $headers = $input['headers'];

        //Sending mail 
        if($result = $this->sendMail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) === true) {
            $response = json_encode(['success' => true]);
            echo $response;
        } else {
            $response = json_encode(['error' => 'Mail Not Sent']);
            die($response);
        }
    }
}

private function sendMail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers) {
    //Configurating PHP Mailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();                                 
    $mail->Host = 'secure.emailsrvr.com';  
    $mail->Port = 995;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                            
    $mail->Username = 'example@example.com';                           
    $mail->Password = '****';                          
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                   
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;      
    $mail->IsHTML(true); 

    $mail->SetFrom('REDACTED@example.com');
    $mail->AddReplyTo($headers);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $mail->AddAddress($to, "");

    if(!$mail->Send())
        return $mail->ErrorInfo;

    return true;
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you able to extract post the HTTP response you got from Postman?

Comment: @light, in postman I just get an empty HTML but in JSON response it says No response returned.

But the response status is 200

Comment: Ok. Analysing the code, I think it's because `die()` simply terminates the PHP script, and hence the webserver returns a "200" indicating success, since your PHP script didn't set the headers otherwise. Now, the issue is: why did the mail fail. What OS are you running?

Comment: I'm using windows 8 and I included the die in a condition so if it failed it should have returned the error message

Comment: Note: Windows doesn't have a SMTP server by default. Also, are you calling `actionSendMail()` at all from your API router/processor/whatever? Maybe you can put some debug return lines at various places in the function and observe what you get using postman.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83037/discussion-between-gideon-appoh-and-light).

Answer (score 0):

You need to test your mail sending code in isolation - errors are being hidden behind your other code. A long delay most likely means you're having a network timeout, either due to bad connectivity or DNS timeout. Try setting `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` so you can see connection errors. Check the [PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Answer (score 0):

use this when checking mail response

```
if($this->sendMail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
    $response = json_encode(['success' => true]);
    echo $response;
} 
else { 
    $response = json_encode(['error' => 'Mail Not Sent']);
    die($response);
}
```